# How to create new S3 bucket in AWS using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

How to create a new S3 bucket in AWS using nodejs?

I need to upload a large number of the image file on the s3 bucket for ease of using and manage the storage space on the cloud instead of my local server storage.

- I am working on IoT project which captures the number of images once motion detects any object in their range. So send me the step to follow the configuration of AWS s3 Bucket integration using nodejs.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [S3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3) module on your node server and read the documentation.

```
var s3 = require('s3');

var client = s3.createClient({
  maxAsyncS3: 20,     // this is the default
  s3RetryCount: 3,    // this is the default
  s3RetryDelay: 1000, // this is the default
  multipartUploadThreshold: 20971520, // this is the default (20 MB)
  multipartUploadSize: 15728640, // this is the default (15 MB)
  s3Options: {
    accessKeyId: "your s3 key",
    secretAccessKey: "your s3 secret",
    // any other options are passed to new AWS.S3()
    // See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#constructor-property
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Manishdan for your kind support. It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 var params = {
   Bucket: "examplebucket", 
   CreateBucketConfiguration: {
   LocationConstraint: "eu-west-1"
  }
};
s3.createBucket(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response      
});
```

For more info read this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createBucket-property)

Answer (score 1):

Check the document on https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html

```
var s3bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'test_bucket/sub_bucket'}});
```

will create an extra file. Take out the params in the parentheses. I found out that Amazon's quick start guide example creates an extra file. This way is the correct way to do it.

```
// Create a bucket using bound parameters and put something in it.
var s3bucket = new AWS.S3();
s3bucket.createBucket(function() {
    var params = {Bucket: 'bucket/sub-bucket', Key: 'file_name1', Body: 'Hello!'};
    s3bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error uploading data: ", err);
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
            res.write("Successfully uploaded data to bucket/sub-bucket/");
            res.end()
        }
    });
});
```